# Applying bootstrap styles to only one section in the page

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm creating a web application without using bootstrap framework. But later I used the bootstrap carousal to my web application. Because I imported the bootstrap framework some of the styles I applied has changed, because different styles has been defined for those elements in bootstrap framework.

**Now I want to add bootstrap framework only to the carousal section of my web application.** So, I tried to change the order of the the link tags where I have imported the bootstrap framework and  my custom style-sheet. But it didn't work.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link rel = "stylesheet" href = "css/main.css" type = "text/css"/>
```

Any help?

Comment: Honestly, if you only want one section - especially the carousel, you only need copy everything relative with it from bootstrap to your css file and modify up to your wish, it the eassiest way i can think of and it not too complicate to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

download bootstrap to your system and include bootstrap.css in your project and remove the conflicting classes from that file..

Comment: Is that the only way?

Comment: that is how I do it because sometimes some classes will not get modiifed even if you overwrite them with styles outside so better i go in and make the modifications there..

Answer (score 1):

call that part in iframe with different webpage and links